# Webgrid MVC Button eliminate element of a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the next grid on the view of my MVC3 model:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.ListFoo, canSort: false);


    @grid.GetHtml(
                        columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("FooElement0", "FooElement0"),
                                grid.Column("FooElement1", "FooElement1"),
                                grid.Column(format: @<button type="submit" name="deleteFoo" value="bleh">DeleteFoo</button>)))
```

How can I pass to the controler the position in the button on the list of this element (the value in "bleh")? I don't have an Id for the element of the ListFoo because is not yet stored in the database and the user can delete many of the elements before the save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
                        columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("FooElement0", "FooElement0"),
                                grid.Column("FooElement1", "FooElement1"),
                                grid.Column(format: (item) => {return new HtmlString("<button type='submit' name='deleteFoo' value='"+item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item)+"'>DeleteFoo</button>");})))
```